# Force download with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, force-download

I need to make a button, and when I click on it I'll do the same if I had such form:

```
<form action="myscript.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="items[]" value="..." />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

and clicked submit. On the **PHP** side I use proper headers and make the force download.

The reason why I can't use a form here, because I have a lot of parameters, and it's not that easy to use a form tag in my **HTML** markup. Moreover, these parameters are dynamically made, so...

But if I use just `$.ajax` of course It won't work, I'll just get php response in this ajax request, but the browser won't start downloading the file

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to initialize a download without leaving the form?

Comment: @Victor plz accept some of previous questions.

Comment: I want to get all necessary information from jquery code and send it as POST to php, and after that start force download. I have an array with a lot of params that I need in php script. But I can't use a form tag because it is not that convenient, only if I add dynamically lots of hidden params through jquery and then use .submit()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just redirect to the download page, if it has the correct headers on that page, it wont change what page they're on, just download the file with a prompt.

Comment: but I can do it only if I use get params, like myscript.php?param1=value1&...., but if I have a lot of data to send It wont be possible because the uri string is limited. And I have a lot of data (actually an array) so I need to send it with post request.

Comment: Set the variables in the session through an ajax call, then redirect to that page and get them out of the session, clear them out, done.

Comment: Yeah, I guess this works. I use codeigniter and there is a method set_flashdata which sets a session variable that will be cleared after next request. Thanks so much, will try it

Comment: perfect, that's what I meant actually.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: Don't use GET.  Use POST instead!

```
<script>
 var info = ""; // Somewhere for the response to go
 var obj = $.post(
             raw_url,
             { var1:value1, var2:value2 },
             function(data) { info = data; } );
</script>
```

On the PHP side, you'll receive any array based data AS an array (thus if value2 were a javascript array, you'll receive it in PHP as an array as well.)